# Project file can't be build error you don't have permission to view it

Tags: android, ios, iphone, xcode, file

Hello may be this is silly question and may be asked before it but i am not getting proper solution for this. I have downloaded one project from the internet and when i am trying to run it/build it the xcode says :

The file “PROJECT NAME” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it..

Can anybody have idea why this is happen ? Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Have you imported contents from the file into your project? Or are you running as is from the original and untouched package?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes i am running the working copy of the project and it is running in another maxbook/xcode but not running in different macbook/xcode.

Comment: So it works on one macbook but not another? Possibly encrypted. I don't know much about that stuff. I would consider downloading it again for each macbook as the files are rarely larger than 50Mbs or download and store on a USB prior to unzipping and make copies from there. 

Are there any notes that come with it?

I ask because it seems like you may have used some of the code in your project without correctly referencing the class names so the project states you don't have permission to use it's contents.

Comment: I have done it before .download source code seperately for each macbook but not working the xcode where i have create the project in that the project build but in another it is not.

Comment: How important is this code? Are you trying to share your code with a team? I am not really understanding what it is you mean. Can you run through your steps like:
1. I run program on my mac. 2. I then upload to bitbucket or something. 3. Download again. 4. try to run and it wont work

Comment: Sorry i can't send you the code. I am finding the other project which have same kind of error i am getting i will send you that code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Take your Projects build Setting
    > In Architecture section make sure that Architectures and Valid Architectures are the same. If any extra Architecture is present in Valid Architecture section please remove it and then try building the code, It will work.![enter image description here][1]
```

[image]

```
Here in the image edit the section marked as red.
```